# How to correctly mix debug and release binaries involving std::string among others?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

I have a c++ project, I want to use it with debug binary, but I also want to use its dependencies no in debug but release.

The problem is that is does not seem possible, in particular when I have `std::string & var` as function arguments, I got memory errors such as:
`Microsoft C++ exception: std::length_error at memory location 0x000000F2111AEE20` when attempting to access to string.

In certain conditions, asking the compiler not to do any inlining helps, but sometimes for specific data (images), it's not sufficient.

How to achieve this ie., having a debug project using release libraries, without rewriting dependents or libraries ? (I want to keep using `string`, and not `char*` or so).

---

Repro: use toolset v141 of VS2017 or VS2019. Use OpenImageIO in release, and project in debug.

```
#include <OpenImageIO/imageio.h>

int main()
{
    auto in = ImageInput::open("SomeImageFile.DPX"); // std::length_error 
    if (in) {
        printf ("Opened successfully, format is %s\n", in->format_name());
    } else {
        printf ("Fail\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Library OpenImageIO source: https://github.com/OpenImageIO/oiio

Image sample: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlUmbfQiLoTZhFOpmgFMMVKtgCOk

Comment: It's odd to me that in debug mode you want to disable a feature that helps you finding errors. The memory error you are getting seems to be something to fix, not to hide in debug

Comment: @GianPaolo I want to debug my code, not that which of the libraries I use.

Comment: @GianPaolo I don't think anyone said anything about hiding the error? The goal is to fix it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Hehe, I thought it was a general problem, maybe it is not. Hence I added some short code example.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `in->format_name()` returns a `const char*`

Comment: Microsoft's standard library implementation adds some data to some things in debug mode, in order to support iterator checking. So, in general, you're in or your out: no mixing. You might be able to disable iterator debugging and get the same object layout both ways, but then, of course, you don't get the iterator debugging.

Comment: @PeteBecker That's a key piece of information.

Comment: You can't. Use separate binaries for debug and release mode (there might be more settings that are binary-incompatible, such as static vs. dynamic C runtime).

Comment: @Soleil according to [this documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/length_error), _This exception is thrown by member functions of std::basic_string and std::vector::reserve_: I would assume that ImageInput class is trying somehow to use invoke `vector::reserve` with a value too big.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, this kind of exception are thrown in debug mode just to help finding bugs, and not in release where for sake of efficency code avoids some checks. Trying to stop these kind of exception in debug means trying to hide errors to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Soleil _I want to debug my code, not that which of the libraries I use_ : that exception is (usually) a signal that your code, using that libraries, is doing something wrong you should fix.

Comment: Have you heard of the One Definition Rule?  What you propose immediately and unrecoverably lands you in the realm of undefined behavior.  What you are looking for is a version of the library with optimization enabled and linked against the debug version of the language support library... you can easily build that version yourself, but it's very rare to see one distributed.

Comment: @Scheff: Take a look at the code, there is only one parameter being passed, and it is a filename.  So the failure is either a One Definition Rule violation, or the library has a buffer overflow vulnerability that this particular input file triggers.

Comment: @BenVoigt I didn't look at the code sample - my failure. Though, for my applications, it doesn't make a difference who wrote the code which fails. If it fails (and I'm able to fix it) I would prefer to get notified about the necessity... (Weak excuse - I know.) ;-)

Comment: @GianPaolo The error is not hidden, it's only missing few symbols, and I get less details, but the library runs reasonnably fast (4 sec debug -> few ms), which is what I want for my unit tests which are testing my code.